# Java Swing - How to put a JTable in a JScrollPane with MigLayout without issues?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, miglayout

I'm trying to put a JTable inside a JScrollPane that is inside a JPanel set to MigLayout.

When I insert the table, I got some issues:

1. the label added to the JScrollPane in the column header is always missing
2. the table size is too large for a couple of rows

Here a self-explaining image:

[image]

and here the simple code I used:

```
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[grow]", "[grow][grow]"));

    JPanel oh_Panel = new JPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(oh_Panel, "cell 0 0,grow");
    oh_Panel.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[grow]", "[grow]"));

    JScrollPane oh_scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    oh_Panel.add(oh_scrollPane, "cell 0 0,grow");

    JTree oh_tree = new JTree();
    oh_scrollPane.setViewportView(oh_tree);

    JLabel oh_label = new JLabel("MyLabel");
    oh_label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    oh_scrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(oh_label);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, "cell 0 1,grow");
    panel.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[grow]", "[grow][]"));

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    panel.add(scrollPane, "cell 0 0,grow");

    table = new JTable(createTable());
    //table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(null);
    //table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

    JLabel labelForTable = new JLabel("MyLabelForTable");
    scrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(labelForTable);

}


private DefaultTableModel createTable() {
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    model.addColumn("Property");
    model.addColumn("Value");
    model.addRow(new String[]{"Name", "John"});
    model.addRow(new String[]{"Surname", "Red"});
    return model;
}
```

Then, I also tried a solution I read in other questions involving either:

```
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(null); AND/OR
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
```

The result is always this:

[image]

I even tried to change the MigLayout to BorderLayout, but nothing changed.

Am I missing something?

Comment: For experimenting set the background color of JScrollPane and JTable to different colors. I am a `new JScrollPane(table)` kind of coder, but that should be the same. You probably will need to use the table size for the scroll pane's size.

Comment: Since you determined you have the same problem when using a MigLayout or BorderLayout, then the code you post should be the BorderLayout version, since MigLayout is a third partly class. Problems should first be solved by using classes of the JDK to make sure the problem isn't with the other class.

Comment: Post an [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the layout managers involved. It has to do with the interaction between a JTable and a JScrollPane.

When a `JTable` is added to the viewport of the `JScrollPane`, then the `JTableHeader` of the `JTable` is used as the column header of the scroll pane. However, the column header is not set until the frame is made displayable. That is, it is added after you invoke pack() or setVisible(true) on the frame. So your attempt to set the column header is being overridden.

If you want to use your own column header then the easiest way is to create your own panel with the two components:

```
JLabel labelForTable = new JLabel("MyLabelForTable");
JTable table = new JTable(3, 2);
JPanel tableWrapper = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
tableWrapper.add(labelForTable, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
tableWrapper.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( tableWrapper );
```